# Get value from cursor everytime when database is updated

Tags: java, android

I've got two activities. One is updating value in database from edittext and in the second activity i want put this value from database into textview. At the first time when i update value everything goes well but at the second time textview cant be updated and i see in the Textview value "0". When i gave breakpoints i see that my cursor didnt want to take value second time. Any suggestion what should i do ? It's problem with lifecycle of activity or what? There is my code. Any example or suggestion will be very helpful for me.

```
public class DzienPierwszy extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;
    OpenHelper1 mDb;
    TextView pp1,pp2,pp3,s1,s2,s3,p1,p2,p3,pn,sr,pt,nd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.dzien_treningu);

        p1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.p1);
        p2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.p2);
        p3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.p3);
        s1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.s1);
        s2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.s2);
        s3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.s3);
        pp1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pp1);
        pp2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pp2);
        pp3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pp3);
        pn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pn);
        sr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sr);
        pt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pt);
        nd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nd);



        Intent i = getIntent();
        final String product = i.getStringExtra("cwiczenie ");
        int lol1=0;

        mDb = new OpenHelper1(this);

        mDb.open();
        // fetch data about 1 row in database table
        Cursor test = mDb.fetchOneCwiczenie(product);

        mDb.close();

        if( test != null && test.moveToFirst() ){
            //get value from column
            lol1 = test.getInt(test.getColumnIndex("score"));
            test.close();
        }


        p1.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(lol1*0.55)));
        p2.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(lol1*0.79)));
        p3.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(lol1*0.67)));
        s1.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(lol1*0.67)));
        s2.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(lol1*0.91)));
        s3.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(lol1*0.79)));
        pp1.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(lol1*0.79)));
        pp2.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(lol1*1.03)));
        pp3.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(lol1*0.91)));

    }

    public void open(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TestActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}




public class OpenHelper1{



private static final String TAG = "TreningDbAdapter";
public DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
private final ContentResolver resolver =null;

private final Context mCtx;

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "menadzerCwiczen1";
public static final String TABLE_CWICZENIA = "cwiczenia";
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_KIND = "kind";
public static final String KEY_URL = "url";
public static final String KEY_SCORE = "score";
public static final String KEY_SERIES = "series";

static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "com.example.jacek.gympartner.SQLite";
static final String URL = "content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/cwiczenia";
static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(URL);

private static HashMap<String, String> CWICZENIA_PROJECTION_MAP;

static final int CWICZENIA = 1;
static final int CWICZENIE_ID = 2;

static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;
static{
    uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "cwiczenie", CWICZENIA);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "cwiczenia/#", CWICZENIE_ID);
}



private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + TABLE_CWICZENIA + " (" +
                KEY_ID + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT," +
                KEY_KIND + " TEXT," +
                KEY_URL + " TEXT," +
                KEY_SCORE + " TEXT," +
                KEY_SERIES + " integer" +
                ");";
/*
@Override
public boolean onCreate() {

    Context context = getContext();
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);



    mDb = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return (mDb == null)? false:true;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    return null;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    return null;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    return 0;
}
*/

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.w(TAG, DATABASE_CREATE);




        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+TABLE_CWICZENIA+"("+KEY_NAME+","+KEY_KIND+","+KEY_URL+","+KEY_SCORE+","+KEY_SCORE+") VALUES('Pompki','Klatka piersiowa','https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwnidT3CB_Q',0,3)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+TABLE_CWICZENIA+"("+KEY_NAME+","+KEY_KIND+","+KEY_URL+","+KEY_SCORE+","+KEY_SCORE+") VALUES('Pompki na poręczach','Triceps','https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cufsu3IHhCo',0,3)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+TABLE_CWICZENIA+"("+KEY_NAME+","+KEY_KIND+","+KEY_URL+","+KEY_SCORE+","+KEY_SCORE+") VALUES('Odwrotne wiosłowanie','Plecy','https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8qCn76yKhro',0,3)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+TABLE_CWICZENIA+"("+KEY_NAME+","+KEY_KIND+","+KEY_URL+","+KEY_SCORE+","+KEY_SCORE+") VALUES('Spięcia brzucha leżąc','Górna część mięśni brzucha','https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVcm4LdmIwM',0,3)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+TABLE_CWICZENIA+"("+KEY_NAME+","+KEY_KIND+","+KEY_URL+","+KEY_SCORE+","+KEY_SCORE+") VALUES('Unoszenie kolan','Dolna część mięśni brzucha','https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Htx9Z8ZkiCg',0,3)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+TABLE_CWICZENIA+"("+KEY_NAME+","+KEY_KIND+","+KEY_URL+","+KEY_SCORE+","+KEY_SCORE+") VALUES('Skręty tułowia','Mięśnie skośne brzucha','https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7smKA3mgBU',0,3)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+TABLE_CWICZENIA+"("+KEY_NAME+","+KEY_KIND+","+KEY_URL+","+KEY_SCORE+","+KEY_SCORE+") VALUES('Przysiady','Uda','https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NEduXlZ8zSk&t',0,3)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+TABLE_CWICZENIA+"("+KEY_NAME+","+KEY_KIND+","+KEY_URL+","+KEY_SCORE+","+KEY_SCORE+") VALUES('Wspięcia na palce','Mięśnie łydek','https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wri0VppFWCY',0,3)");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+TABLE_CWICZENIA+"("+KEY_NAME+","+KEY_KIND+","+KEY_URL+","+KEY_SCORE+","+KEY_SCORE+") VALUES('Podciąganie na drążku','Mięśnie łydek','https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7hM1iriAxx8',0,3)");


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CWICZENIA);

        onCreate(db);
    }



}

public  OpenHelper1(Context ctx) {
    this.mCtx = ctx;
}

public OpenHelper1 open() throws SQLException {
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public OpenHelper1 read() throws SQLException {
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    if (mDbHelper != null) {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }
}

public long createCwiczenie(String name,
                          String kind,
                          String url,
                          int score,
                          int series) {
    mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    initialValues.put(KEY_KIND, kind);
    initialValues.put(KEY_URL, url);
    initialValues.put(KEY_SCORE, score);
    initialValues.put(KEY_SERIES, series);

    return mDb.insert(TABLE_CWICZENIA, null, initialValues);
}


public void deleteCwiczenie(String name) {
    mDb.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_CWICZENIA + " WHERE " + KEY_NAME + "=\"" + name + "\";" );
}



public void updateScore1(Uri uri,String name, int wynik) {
    String str = "UPDATE "+TABLE_CWICZENIA+" SET "+KEY_SCORE+" = "+wynik+" WHERE "+KEY_NAME+" = '"+name+"'";
    mDb.execSQL(str);
}


public void updateScore(String name, int wynik) {
    String str = "UPDATE "+TABLE_CWICZENIA+" SET "+KEY_SCORE+" = "+wynik+" WHERE "+KEY_NAME+" = '"+name+"'";
    mDb.execSQL(str);
}
public boolean deleteAllCwiczenia() {

    int doneDelete = 0;
    doneDelete = mDb.delete(TABLE_CWICZENIA, null , null);
    Log.w(TAG, Integer.toString(doneDelete));
    return doneDelete > 0;

}

public Cursor fetchCwiczeniaByName(String inputText) throws SQLException {
    Log.w(TAG, inputText);
    Cursor mCursor = null;
    if (inputText == null  ||  inputText.length () == 0)  {
        mCursor = mDb.query(TABLE_CWICZENIA, new String[] {KEY_ID,
                        KEY_NAME, KEY_KIND, KEY_URL, KEY_SCORE, KEY_SERIES},
                null, null, null, null, null);

    }
    else {
        mCursor = mDb.query(true, TABLE_CWICZENIA, new String[] {KEY_ID,
                        KEY_NAME, KEY_KIND, KEY_URL, KEY_SCORE, KEY_SERIES},
                KEY_NAME + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null,
                null, null, null, null);
    }
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;

}

public Cursor fetchAllcwiczenia() {

    Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(TABLE_CWICZENIA, new String[] {KEY_ID,
                    KEY_NAME, KEY_KIND, KEY_URL, KEY_SCORE, KEY_SERIES},
            null, null, null, null, null);

    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}

public Cursor fetchOneCwiczenie(String name) {

    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CWICZENIA + " WHERE name='"+name+"'";

    Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery(query,null);


    if(c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

public Cursor fetchOneCwiczenie1(Uri uri,String name) {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    qb.setTables(TABLE_CWICZENIA);



    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CWICZENIA + " WHERE name='"+name+"'";

    Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery(query,null);


    if (c != null) {
       // c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), ContactsContract.AUTHORITY_URI);
    }

    return c;
}




public void insertSomeCwiczenia() {
    createCwiczenie("Pompki","Klatka piersiowa","https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwnidT3CB_Q",20,3);
    createCwiczenie("Pompki na poręczach","Triceps","https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cufsu3IHhCo",0,3);
    createCwiczenie("Odwrotne wiosłowanie","Plecy","https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8qCn76yKhro",0,3);
    createCwiczenie("Spięcia brzucha leżąc","Górna część mięśni brzucha","https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVcm4LdmIwM",0,3);
    createCwiczenie("Unoszenie kolan","Dolna część mięśni brzucha","https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Htx9Z8ZkiCg",0,3);
    createCwiczenie("Skręty tułowia","Mięśnie skośne brzucha","https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7smKA3mgBU",0,3);
    createCwiczenie("Przysiady","Uda","https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NEduXlZ8zSk&t",0,3);
    createCwiczenie("Wspięcia na palce","Mięśnie łydek","https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wri0VppFWCY",0,3);
    createCwiczenie("Podciąganie na drążku","Mięśnie łydek","https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7hM1iriAxx8",0,3);
}


}

public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView textView;
EditText editText;
Button button,button1;
OpenHelper1 mDb;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.polecenie);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wartosc);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.treningactivity);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.zapisz);
    //button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);



    mDb = new OpenHelper1(this);



    Intent i = getIntent();
    // getting attached intent data
    final String product = i.getStringExtra("cwiczenie ");



    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int wynik = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
            mDb.open();
            mDb.updateScore(product,wynik);


            mDb.close();


        }
    });

    /*
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mDb.open();
            Cursor t = mDb.fetchOneCwiczenie(product);
            int c = t.getInt(t.getColumnIndex("score"));
            String k = Integer.toString(c);
            textView1.setText(k);
            mDb.close();

        }
    });
    */

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext().getApplicationContext(), DzienPierwszy.class);
            i.putExtra("cwiczenie ", product);

            startActivity(i);
        }
    });



}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more than couple of things that you need to do -

1. In your content provider, you need to attach a notification Uri before the Cursor is being returned to client (in this case your Activity). The code would look something like this (Here the Authority URI need to be changed as per your provider) -

`if (c != null) {
     c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(),ContactsContract.AUTHORITY_URI);
}
return c;`

2. Every time there is a update in data, the following line needs to be called -

`getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY_URI, null,
                syncToNetwork);`

Basically what point 1  & 2 does is that it notifies the underlying data layer that there is currently a client with an active cursor and needs to be notified if there is a change in the underlying data. If you are using any of the inbuilt data providers in Android like ContactsProvider/SmsProvider to read contacts/SMS data, point 1 &2 would have been taken care.

[ContactsProvider](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/ContactsProvider/+/master/src/com/android/providers/contacts/ContactsProvider2.java)

3. And on your activity code you need to do something like
   `cursor.registerContentObserver(mChangeObserver)`. If you instead use a Cursor adapter which wraps around your cursor, then this would have been taken care. Have a look at the Cursor Adapter source code -

[CursorAdapter Sample](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/1a008c1/core/java/android/widget/CursorAdapter.java)

Comment: But you know maybe why there is a value "0"? When im creating table there is a value "0". It's reseting it all the time when i'm changing Activity? I will explan u how my program is working. Im opening a tab layout where i got 4 fragments. In every fragment i got listview which getting data from database. Everytime when im opening program im deleting all tables and im creating new ones. When i click on the single list item im opening activity where i got buttons.

Comment: In the first button i got activity with this EditText which i said earlier with updating column and second button
    with TextView where i want to get value to edittext which i said too. It can be problem with that im creating table every time when i open program?

Comment: It's going to be too complicated for me. I'm new in android maybe 2 months im programming in it. Can u tell me everything more simple ? Or give me a good advice how to managed with that like for beginner ?

Comment: By the sounds of it, I will suggest you to cover some basics on the Android components. Unless you have a fairly good understanding of the basic building blocks, things are always going to be complex :)  Go through the Android training materials on dev site

Comment: Hi again. I read something about it. But still i have problem with implamantion it. I updated this post and i gave u all classes what u need. Can u help me ?

Comment: I made a new database from beginning. I made content provider and by CursorLoader i automatically refresh my value from database.